# CSS background color is not visible in nested display blocks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't reproduce this, but I swear I have this similar code, where background red is not visible on items within the `lines` element. That is `World` text is not red.

```css
.wrap {
  background: red;
}

lines {
  display: block;
}

lines line- {
  display: block;
}

move {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <replay>
  <moves>
    <move>
      Hello
    </move>
        <move>
      Hello
    </move>
        <move>
      Hello
    </move>
  <lines>
    <line->
      <move>
      World
      </move>
            <move>
      World
      </move>
            <move>
      World
      </move>
            <move>
      World
      </move>
    </line->
  </lines>
  </moves>
  </replay>
</div>
```

If I remove the `display: block` in one of the `lines` or `line` items, the background covers an entire area as expected.

Here's a real snippet of dom:

```html
<vchessreplay>
  <moves>
    <move class="hi">
      <index>1.</index>d4
    </move>
    <comment></comment>
    <move class="hi">d5</move>
    <comment></comment>
    <move class="hi">
      <index>2.</index>Bf4
    </move>
    <comment></comment>
    <move class="hi">c5</move>
    <comment></comment>
    <move class="hi">
      <index>3.</index>e3</move>
      <comment></comment>
      <lines>
        <line->
          <move class="">
            <index>3...</index>cxd4
          </move>
          <comment></comment>
            <move class="">
              <index>4.</index>exd4
            </move>
          <comment></comment>
        </line->
        <line->
          <move class="hi">
            <index>3...</index>Qb6
          </move>
          <comment></comment>
          <move class="hi">
            <index>4.</index>Nc3
          </move>
          <comment></comment>
          <move class="hi">e6</move>
          <comment></comment>
          <move class="hi">
            <index>5.</index>Nf3
          </move>
          <comment></comment>
          <lines>
            <line->
              <move class="">
                <index>5...</index>Be7
              </move>
              <comment> Hello world </comment>
              <move class="">
                <index>6.</index>a5
              </move>
              <comment> What s up ok ok ok ook </comment>
              <move class="">Qd8</move>
              <comment></comment>
            </line->
            <line->
              <move class="hi">
                <index>5...</index>c4
              </move>
              <comment></comment>
              <move class="hi">
                <index>6.</index>b3
              </move>
              <comment></comment>
              <move class="hi">b5</move>
              <comment></comment>
              <move class="hi">
                <index>7.</index>Rb1
              </move>
              <comment></comment>
              <lines>
                <line->
                  <move class="hi">
                    <index>7...</index>Qa5
                  </move>
                  <comment></comment>
                  <lines>
                    <line->
                      <move class="">
                        <index>8.</index>Rxb7
                      </move>
                      <comment></comment>
                      <move class="">Qxc3</move>
                      <comment></comment>
                    </line->
                    <line->
                      <move class="hi">
                        <index>8.</index>Bxc4</move>
                        <comment></comment>
                        <move class="hi">Qxc7</move>
                        <comment></comment>
                      </line->
                    </lines>
                  </line->
                  <line->
                    <move class="">
                      <index>7...</index>Qd7
                    </move>
                    <comment></comment>
                    <move class="">
                      <index>8.</index>Ne5
                    </move>
                    <comment></comment>
                  </line->
                </lines>
              </line->
            </lines>
          </line->
        </lines>
      </moves>
    </vchessreplay>
```

Comment: Also If i give display:flex to `.wrap` element background colors everywhere red as expected again.

Answer (score 1):

Why using not standard html node names with classes for styling?

```css
.wrap {
    background: red;
}

.lines {
    display: block;
}

.lines .line {
    display: block;
}

.move {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="replay">
        <div class="moves">
            <div class="move">Hello</div>
            <div class="move">Hello</div>
            <div class="move">Hello</div>
            <div class="lines">
                <div class="line" id="line-1">
                    <div class="move">World</div>
                    <div class="move">World</div>
                    <div class="move">World</div>
                    <div class="move">World</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a drawback for using custom elements i've seen it used in production code.

Comment: It surely depends where your code is running, why do you need custom tag names in the first place? If you need to specify custom data, you could use data-* attribute on standard html elements.

Comment: Because it looks cool, and less verbose, also I've seen it is used in large code bases, so why is that bothers you? I just need to support all major browsers that's all.

Comment: Then use standard html tags or at least drop "-"...

Comment: That caused a weird issue where I used line and styles didn't apply, something to do with custom element syntax I guess.